# What dose it mean condition $\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}\le 1$for natural numbers pair $(a_1,a_2, a_3)$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Sorry for my bad English.

For natural numbers pair $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ such that $1\le a_1\le \cdots \le a_n$, we can think the following condition

> $\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots +\frac{1}{a_n}\le 1.$

I want to know more information about this topic, especially the case$n=3$.

At once we have $a_n\ge n$ is necessary condition and if $a_n=n$ then $(a_1,\dots,a_n)=(n,\dots,n)$.

On the other hand $a_1=n$ is sufficient condition.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking why these conditions imply this inequality? Or something more philosophical about what this inequality really means? I don't want to vote to close the question as unclear if it's just because English is not your first language, but as it stands, well, it's unclear.

Comment: Sorry, just you say my first language is not English. I think this inequality is very simple so I'm sure there is already ample and developed theory about this topic.But I can't find such theory so if you know, please tell me the reference.

Comment: If you're not sure why these conditions imply this inequality is true, just try your example. Pick a few integers and see why it works.

Comment: I know why  these conditions imply this inequality is true. I want to know more informations.

Comment: One thing I know about this inequality in the case of $n=3$ is that you can cook up homology $3$-spheres this way. I learned the construction from Martelli's book on geometric topology. You could check that out.